# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context at the initialization

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

What can be a problem here?

```
class BookCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

// Some code

    private let itemFavoritingService: ItemFavouriting?


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        setupViews()
    }
    
    init(itemFavoritingService: ItemFavouriting? = nil) {
        self.itemFavoritingService = itemFavoritingService
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
 }
```

Shows error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: What class is this in?

Comment: set ```super.init(frame: .zero)``` insted of ```super.init(nibName..``` and set nil value to itemFavoritingService

Comment: @Sweeper its inside of cell class. P.s. edited the code to show the class

Answer (score 2):

There is no

```
super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

init inside a collection cell , use init frame/coder only

[image]